# Sending string of text from iPhone to PC [iOS to VB.NET]

Tags: ios, vb.net

All I need to do is when I press a button on my app, a string of text (eg. "text1"), to my PC where my VB.NET application can interpret it. Can this be done in a simple way? Pretty much if I could get my iPhone app to store data on a webpage for 30 seconds my VB.NET application could then take that data.

I have looked at [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) but that really wouldn't be plausible I don't think, unless you can explain how I could make it listening while the Vb.NET application is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Web-Service on C# and call it and pass the parameters values to it from your ios-application.